# Intellij IDEA Cannot Undo

Tags: intellij-idea, undo, revert

I am working on a project at Intellij IDEA. I moved refactored some packages. However I want to undo my changes. When I click revert button it says

`Cannot Undo`

and shows a list under that:

`Following files affected by this action have been already changed`

How can I revert my changes because I lost some packages and classes. Does Intellij IDEA keeps them inside a temporary folder?

**PS:** I use open jdk 1.6.0 on a 64 bit Ubuntu computer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has a great feature called as **local history**. I could revert my changes. <strike>There is a video gives a detailed example for it:</strike>

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/training/demos/local_history.html

You can get more information from here:  http://jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/using-local-history.html

Comment: Thanks to Serge Baranov from Intellij IDEA support team. He answered my question immediately when I asked from support page.

Comment: Yes, IntelliJ support guys are awesome that's one of the reasons (not the only one) for which I prefer IntelliJ over Eclipse

Comment: But in case I want revert change then i really want to revert the change. but it still shows in i checking from the directory. Keeping local history is one thing but keeping the history for the SVN is another. I expect the intellij not to show anything in the SVN commit or revert once the file has been reverted.

Comment: annnnnd link's dead

Comment: @pennstatephil here is an explanation instead of dead link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/using-local-history.html

Comment: Answers that are links aren't generally accepted as answers because links can die.  Please flesh out your answer with the contents from the link.

Answer (score 16):

Undo it through VCS --> Local History --> Show History.

Answer (score 3):

As I googled to here several times when I developing IntelliJ plugin [emacsIDEAs](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea_ce&pluginId=7163), I will leave my solution here for someone who need it.

usually change to document need be done in **runWriteAction**, 
and for undo changes to document need called in **CommandProcessor.getInstance().executeCommand**

so the solution is: call **executeCommand** in **runWriteAction**, then the changes will be undoable.

```
protected Runnable getRunnableWrapper(final Runnable runnable) {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CommandProcessor.getInstance().executeCommand(_editor.getProject(), runnable, "cut", ActionGroup.EMPTY_GROUP);
        }
    };
}

final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        selectJumpArea(jumpTargetOffset);
        _editor.getSelectionModel().copySelectionToClipboard();
        EditorModificationUtil.deleteSelectedText(_editor);
        _editor.getSelectionModel().removeSelection();
    }
};

ApplicationManager.getApplication().runWriteAction(getRunnableWrapper(runnable));
```

code repo: https://github.com/whunmr/emacsIDEAs