# Cannot Undo my temporary changes in Intellij Using Command+Z

Tags: intellij-idea, undo

I am facing some issue while reverting my recent temporary changes using command+z(Mac) in intellij idea I am not sure how i can resolve this?
[image]

** these are temporary changes not git commit one **

i followed these link before asking this question but both link include git related changes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106126/intellij-idea-cannot-undo)

Comment: Does it make any difference if you disable the bundled "Code With Me" plugin? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html

Comment: If the problem remains contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and share the IDE logs after restarting the IDE and reproducing the problem. `Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data`